How to add a scrollbar to a frame with tkinter
I am trying to make my own kanban board. I need four columns and some cards in them.
I have two issues at the moment:

Each column is not exactly the same size, if there is no card, the column is just not visible.
If there are too many cards, I cannot scroll over the desired column.

I have seen that I can't add a scrollbar to a frame but I don't see how I can solve my problem then. Can I ask for your help?
Here is my current code:
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Scrollbar, font
from tkinter import Frame, Label, Text
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

COLUMNS = ["To Do", "In Progress", "Blocked", "Done"]


class Card(Frame):

    last_id = 0

    def __init__(self, dashboard, title, column):
        super().__init__(column, bg="lightblue", padx=10, pady=5, relief="raised")

        self.id = type(self).last_id
        type(self).last_id += 1
        self.dashboard = dashboard
        self.column = column

        self.title = title
        title_text = Text(self, borderwidth=0, bg="lightblue", height=2)
        title_text.insert(1.0, title)
        title_text.configure(
            state="disabled", font=font.nametofont("TkTextFont").actual()
        )
        title_text.pack(padx=5, side="top", fill="x")

        due_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
        due_date_label = Label(self, text=f"Due date: {due_date}")
        due_date_label.pack(padx=5, side="top", fill="x")

        self.combobox = Combobox(self, values=["Move to:"] + COLUMNS)
        self.combobox.current(0)
        self.combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.move_card)
        self.combobox.pack(padx=5, side="top", fill="x")

        self.pack(padx=5, pady=5, fill="x")

    def move_card(self, event):
        new_column = self.combobox.get()
        if new_column == "Move to:":
            return
        if not self.dashboard.frames[new_column] == self.column:
            self.dashboard.cards.remove(self)
            self.dashboard.cards.append(
                Card(self.dashboard, self.title, self.dashboard.frames[new_column])
            )
            self.destroy()
        else:
            self.combobox.current(0)


class SprintDashBoard(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Drag and Drop Cards")
        self.geometry("1200x600")
        # self.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for i, column in enumerate(COLUMNS):
            frame = Frame(self, bg="#f0f0f0", relief="sunken", bd=1)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
            label = Label(frame, text=column, bg="#d3d3d3")
            label.pack(fill="x")
            self.frames[column] = frame
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.cards = []
        self.cards.append(
            Card(self, "Task 1 is a very long text to talk about", self.frames["To Do"])
        )
        self.cards.append(Card(self, "Task 4", self.frames["To Do"]))
        self.cards.append(Card(self, "Task 2", self.frames["In Progress"]))
        self.cards.append(Card(self, "Task 3", self.frames["Blocked"]))
        # self.cards.append(Card(self, "Task 5", self.frames["Done"]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SprintDashBoard()
    app.mainloop()

I tried to use ScrolledText without success, I don't know how to give a width to the frame.

Set the uniform option so that the column remains visible even if it is empty. self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1, uniform='a')
